# Codename One Timer issues

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm trying to use a timer in Codename One, but it only has "UITimer" which I can't seem to figure out nor find any examples of.

So I tried the swing timer but it's giving me the error:

> `codename1.ui.events.ActionListener cannot be converted to java.awt.event.ActionListener`

with this code

```
tim = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

      }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the import for awt and never import those classes.

UITimer works with an action event but you used timer. If you used Timer from javax.swing then remove all of those imports which are also a mistake.

If you use java.util.Timer you should use a TimerTask and not an action listener. This is an issue with NetBeans that doesn't allow setting individual project bootclasspath hence imports classes we don't support and won't compile.

UITimer samples are at the end of the developer guide: http://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html
and all over the discussion forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/codenameone-discussions/UITimer

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is an ambiguity about which `ActionListener` class your code refers to, as you probably imported the CodeNameOne instead of the Java built-in one, or both have been improted.

In the first case just replace `import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener;` by `import java.awt.event.ActionListener;`.

In the case you need both classes to be imported you'll have to prefix the class's name with it's package name. In your case you want to use the class from the Java package :

```
tim = new Timer(1000, new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Seems to me like it's actually the other way around. The OP probably has the codename ActionListener imported, which cant be passed to the Timer as it takes only an awt.ActionListener.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It's not giving immediate errors, but giving this error when I try to run the project:
"error: package javax.swing does not exist
import javax.swing.Timer;".

But I did import it so I really don't get it.

Comment: I think this comes from your project's configuration, which appear to be broken. Are you using Eclipse ?

Comment: Using netbeans, and from what I've googled it seems to be a pretty widespread problem. I've tried clearing my chache but it didn't work.

Comment: I just realized I can solve my problem by using the Date function and subtracting the current time from the started time. But when I call Date's toString function on the current date it gives me March 1, 01:00:00, 2014 which is not correct